# How to send data from RecyclerAdapter class to Main Activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am extending FirestoreAdapter Class to populate the data from firestore .How can i pass the on item selected Tittle to the main Class . I using the interface to send the document ID of the selected item with that how can i pass the selected tittle i.e TextView of the item clicked.Or should i use Intent.put extra to pass it to main Activity.Thanks in Advance
My Code:

```
public class CategoryMainAdapter extends FirestoreAdapter<CategoryMainAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = "CategoryMainAdapter";

public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
    void OnItemSelected(DocumentSnapshot item);

}

private OnItemSelectedListener mListener;


public CategoryMainAdapter(Query query,OnItemSelectedListener listener) {
    super(query);
    mListener = listener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    return new ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.categories_list,parent,false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(getSnapshot(position),mListener);
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ImageView CategoryImageView;
    TextView CategoryTextView;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        CategoryImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Cateimage_view);
        CategoryTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
    }

    public void bind(final DocumentSnapshot snapshot, final OnItemSelectedListener mListener) {

        MainCategory category = snapshot.toObject(MainCategory.class);
        Resources resources = itemView.getResources();

        CategoryTextView.setText(category.getCategory_name());
        Glide.with(CategoryImageView.getContext())
                .load(category.getCategory_url())
                .into(CategoryImageView);

        //Click Listener
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mListener != null){
                    mListener.OnItemSelected(snapshot);
                }
            }
        });
```

to pass this one with the interface:
CategoryTextView.setText(category.getCategory_name());

Comment: You mean you want to pass text present in textview to MainActivity from adapter is it?

Comment: yes i need to pass the textView

Comment: You can do that in the same interface right?

Comment: yes I implemented in same interface .. thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented in the same interface..

```
public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
    void OnItemSelected(DocumentSnapshot item , String Cat_tittle);

}

//Click Listener
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mListener != null){
                    mListener.OnItemSelected(snapshot, String.valueOf(CategoryTextView.getText()));
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just extend your Listener like this

```
public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
void OnItemSelected(DocumentSnapshot item);
void OnItemClicked(String textViewText);
}
```

and

```
//Click Listener
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mListener != null){
                mListener.OnItemSelected(snapshot);
                mListener.OnItemClicked(CategoryTextView.getText());
            }
        }
    });
```

You can use the same listener and extend it how you like. Also, you can save your category data in list with holder position and use it later, when you like (maybe in click listener)